# Regex to allow only valid sentences, not allow all numbers, all spaces, and all special charecters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a Regex to validate a sentence.

Valid case:

```
Can't approve this policy
Premium should be greater than $2500
Annual income above €10.000,00
```

Invaid cases:

```
@#$@#$@#$
12312312312
<all spaces>
```

Regex I currently have
`[A-Za-z0-9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your string should start with an uppercase character and can contain any non whitespace character in the word you might also use:

`^[A-Z]\S*(?: \S+)*$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hjHsnd/1)

That will match:

- `^` Start of the string
- `[A-Z]` Match an uppercase character
- `\S*` Match 0+ times not a whitespace character
- `(?: \S+)*` Repeat 0+ times a non capturing group which matches a space and 1+ times a non whitespace character
- `^` End of the string

Answer (score 1):

So what you want is:

- Start with a capital letter: `^` matches start of input, `[A-Z]` matches capital letter
- Words, one or more time (defined liberally by any non-space character): any non-space chars one or more times is `[^ ]+`, and one or more of those separated by space is `([^ ]+ )*([^ ]+)`
- End of line: `$`

Regex: `/^[A-Z]([^ ]+ )*([^ ]+)?$/`

Comment: Exactly what I wanted!
could you please break it down a little for the readers and me as well?